# Странные арифметические мувы

Tags: java

Решал одну задачку из ЕГЭ, решил сумму кубов сделать через костыль `(a * a * a + b * b * b)`
Получил неправильный ответ
Переписал как `(int) (Math.pow(a, 3) + Math.pow(b, 3))` и получил верный ответ
То есть весь вопрос в том, **почему** `(a * a * a + b * b * b) != (int) (Math.pow(a, 3) + Math.pow(b, 3))`

***Пы.Сы.*** Не вижу смысла приводить весь код, потому что загвоздка именно в этом моменте. Но если нужно - пишите, выложу

Гитхаб с кодом (входные данные в ткст): https://github.com/nikitafront/java/tree/main

Comment: вводные данные какие? что получил в первом варианте и что во втором? небось float возводил в степень?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в обоих случаях онли натуральные числа возводились в куб

Comment: Покажите входные данные и результаты

Comment: @AlexeyTen добавил гитхаб

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не совсем понял Вашу идею
Но в примере - сумма кубов

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy почему костыль (а * а * а ....) переполняется, а функция - нет?

Comment: Я без понятия что делает Java при переполнении, но int ограничен 2^31 и запросто достигается. Вагную что проблема именно в этом. А `Math.pow` кастует во float и переполнения не происходит

Comment: @AlexeyTen но я же сумму в конечном счёте преобразовываю к инту

Comment: Ну сделайте простую проверку что у вас выведет `int a = 2000; System.out.println(a*a*a);`
И подумайте…

Comment: @AlexeyTen дело в том, что ответ - куб 433,...
То есть 2 числа в сумме явно меньше 500, говорить о переполнении типа не приходится

Comment: ‍♂️ Ещё раз перечитайте предыдущий комментарий

Comment: "в обоих случаях онли натуральные числа возводились в куб" - в файле есть большие отрицательные числа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один пример из файла:

```
public class Temp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        int a = -7112;
        int b = -6737;
        System.out.println("a * a * a = " + a * a * a);
        System.out.println("b * b * b = " + b * b * b);
        System.out.println("a * a * a + b * b * b = " + (a * a * a + b * b * b));
        System.out.println("Math.pow(a, 3) = " + Math.pow(a, 3));
        System.out.println("Math.pow(b, 3) = " + Math.pow(b, 3));
        System.out.println("Math.pow(a, 3) + Math.pow(b, 3) = " + (Math.pow(a, 3) + Math.pow(b, 3)));
        System.out.println("(int)(Math.pow(a, 3) + Math.pow(b, 3)) = " + (int)(Math.pow(a, 3) + Math.pow(b, 3)));
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ javac Temp.java && java Temp 
> a * a * a = 1048423936
> b * b * b = -830679537
> a * a * a + b * b * b = 217744399
> Math.pow(a, 3) = -3.59728828928E11
> Math.pow(b, 3) = -3.05773357553E11
> Math.pow(a, 3) + Math.pow(b, 3) = -6.65502186481E11
> (int)(Math.pow(a, 3) + Math.pow(b, 3)) = -2147483648
> ```

Оба тройных произведения переполняются. Их сумма в виде целого числа положительна (это вопрос везения, знак результата может быть любой).

Обе степени не переполняются, так как считаются в `double`. Их сумма большое отрицательное число. Особенность приведения `double` -> `int` в Java в том что когда `double` слишком мал, он переводится в минимальное целое значение (`-2^31`).

То есть, целочисленный вариант выдал положительный мусор, вещественный - отрицательный мусор. Но отрицательный мусор не влияет на результат вашей программы - вы ищете некоторый максимум.